# StackOverflow/Meta were unreachable - Error 429 Too many requests

Tags: support, bug

I don't know if it was just me, but as of approximately 8:46 PM (EST) tonight, I was unable to reach StackOverflow.com and meta.stackoverflow.com but was able to reach other areas other than those.

Then, as of approximately 10:00 pm tonight, both were accessible again.

I kept getting the following message in my browsers being on three different networks/machines and was sure that it was not a local issue.

**Error 429 Too many requests

Too many requests

Guru Mediation:

Details: cache-jfk1034-JFK (sequence of different numbers)

Varnish cache server**

I visited their Twitter account but nothing was posted and Google'd for a while with no significant results.

I even tried contacting a few of my friends to see if they too were seeing the same thing as I, but they were unreachable.

Can someone shed some light on this for me? I find this to be quite bizarre.

---

Edit/update:

(As I made this update), Stack Status still has nothing showing about yesterday's outage https://twitter.com/stackstatus

[Andrew T](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2821954/andrew-t) posted the following link in comments which is related to my question:

- [Error 429 Too many requests on stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281934/error-429-too-many-requests-on-stackoverflow-com)

Being an (probable) issue with SQL maintenance, however it seems it may not have been the case.

There hasn't been a definite answer to this (question) yet.

Consult with the comments below also.

Comment: Duplicate on MSE: [Error 429 Too many requests on stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281934/error-429-too-many-requests-on-stackoverflow-com). There's SQL maintenance, probably that's the cause.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks Andrew. I saw that Amani posted an answer and the comments under his question. That explains why I didn't see the Stack status at the time nor even now. *"I’ll post to Stack Status tonight."* https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/760235722410459136 well, he didn't lol https://twitter.com/stackstatus

Comment: I was getting this continually yesterday, after triggering a bunch of errors in Documentation. The fix? Shutting off my company VPN. I think my IP had been blacklisted for causing too many HTTP 500 responses. I know they said it was maintenance, but I was trying for 45 minutes straight with no luck. Shut down the VPN, no more problems.

Comment: But the tweet says that the outage will occur on Wednesday at 9PM EST, not Monday at 9PM EST.

Comment: @miken32 I had thought about resetting my router/modem at one point, yet I didn't because I truly felt that it wasn't a local issue. Your outage was 45 minutes, compared to my 75. It fixed itself so this tells me that someone was doing something, somewhere.

Comment: @Andrew Yes I know and that adds to more confusion.

Comment: I think my outage would have lasted longer had I not been able to change my IP address...

Comment: @miken32 Do you think it might even be cookie-related? I thought of clearing those too and I should have in order to test it out but didn't. If Stack/Meta holds our login info in files while logged in, then something may have been temporarily disabled; it's hard to say given that I/some/we don't know the actual logistics.

Comment: No, that was my first thought. I tried logging out, and using different browsers, including one I never use.

Comment: @miken32 I couldn't even logout myself (well, not from Stack/Meta that is). I didn't try on any of the other section I was able to access. Maybe a tech'll pick up on my question and shed some light on all this.

Comment: Sorry, yes when I say I logged out I just erased all my browser cookies.

Comment: It's funny, I had this exact issue yesterday and it was **only** present on Chrome! Going through FF/IE all worked. It eventually went away after an hour or so

Comment: @Darren I tried different browsers (on different machines) and still had the same message.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ah you *win*! I'll send the cookies over ;-)

Comment: @Darren Great. I'm getting hungry waiting for an "answer" here *lol!*